# How to detect first day of a month with Day.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, dayjs

I am building a calendar component in React without using any library but `Day.js`.

I need to detect the first weekday of the month in order to leave a gap as shown in the picture. Otherwise the first day of every month has to be Sunday. How can I detect the first weekday of the given date?

[image: calendar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Day.js has built in function to achieve this

```
dayjs().startOf("month").day()
```

This method returns current month's first week day as number.

0 = Sunday,
6 = Saturday

Comment: dayjs().date(1).format("d") will also do that.